# Targeting Webpage Elements With Identical Names

Tags: excel, vba

Short version:

I need a way to use Excel's VBA scripting to interact with a drop down list widget in on a page that has many such widgets each with the same class name.

Long version:

I am trying to write a vba script that will provide links to documentation at the following site:

https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/products/6es7516-3an01-0ab0/cpu-1516-3-pn-dp-1mb-prog-5mb-data?pid=578298&mlfb=6ES7516-3AN01-0AB0&mfn=ps&lc=en-WW

The link above is for a single product.
Obviously I'd like the script to be able to get documentation for any product.

The issue I am having is that I need to interact with a drop down list that is nested rather far into the document.
I can create a loop that locates the list in the page:

```
'Dim NamePeek
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = 1
ie.navigate "https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/products/6es7516-3an01-0ab0/cpu-1516-3-pn-dp-1mb-prog-5mb-data?pid=578298&mlfb=6ES7516-3AN01-0AB0&mfn=ps&lc=en-WW"
Set Divs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each Div In Divs
    'NamePeek = Div.className
    If Div.className = "productfilter mfn" Then
        Trigger01 = True
        Trigger02 = False
        Trigger03 = False
    End If
    If Div.className = "filtertitle" Then
        Trigger02 = True
        Trigger03 = False
    End If
    If Div.className = "dropdown" Then
        Trigger03 = True
    End If
    If Trigger01 And Trigger02 And Trigger03 Then
        'This is where the list I'd like to interact with is located.
        'Div.selectedIndex = 2
        Trigger01 = False
        Trigger02 = False
        Trigger03 = False
    End If
Next Div
```

I know that 'Div.selectedIndex = 2 will not work because there is no .selectedIndex method available to the HTMLDivElement object that the website data gets loaded into in Excel.

I tried making a simple test web page with just a single drop down and used the following to successfully interact with it:

```
Dim target As MSHTML.IHTMLSelectElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = 1

ie.navigate "file:///C:/xxxxxx/dropdowntestwebsite.html"

Set target = ie.document.getElementById("DDList")
target.selectedIndex = 3
```

So I am wondering if I can use IHTMLSelectElement to interact with the drop down on the Siemens site since there are no IDs and the IHTMLSelectElement object does not support the .getElement(s)ByTagName method.

Answer (score 0):

The siemens site looks like it is using some kind of jquery addin to control its elements.  Is widgets an addin?  The select boxes are not hardcoded so you can't control them like a simple select box, say like

```
ie.getelementbyid("selectbox_div").selectedindex = 2.
```

You have to find the javascript command that drops and populates the dropdown and then issue that command through vba, like

```
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("nameofFunctionHere()", "JavaScript")
```

I'm having a similar problem with a website using the addin "Select2" for drop down boxes.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for a javascript function.

Comment: Your link inside your code correctly chose the product code you wanted.  I changed a couple of other select boxes on the Siemens website and then copied the new url.  When I pasted it into a new tab it opened up the page with my new changes present.  Maybe you can just use the url to select what needs to be selected. Try selecting all the things you need for a single item and then copy that url.  You should be able to figure out which part of the url controls whic select boxes.  Figuring out the url code and inserting your choices into that might be easier.

Comment: I noticed that as well. However there is a part of the url that is almost impossible to determine procedurally: .../cpu-1516-3-pn-dp-1mb-prog-5mb-data?pid=578298... I could definitely use the url to select certain boxes but the issue with this method would be trying to select an aritrary product. I wouldn't know what this plain english description would be ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent several weeks trying to fix a webpage using the select2 dropin, so I know what you are going through.  I didn't know that MSHTML couldn't use getelementbyTagname.  Maybe you should try setting it otherwise.  Here is the code I use to take control of open web pages.  Of course the page has to be already open in MSIE and you must know at least part of the document title.

The following code will set it for you and then you can use getElementByTagName.  Sometimes you can get the parent element of the one you want as parentsID.firschild....

```
Sub getSiemensBrowserAlreadyOpen()

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows

    Boolean_indicator = False

    Do While Not Boolean_indicator
    For Each ow In objAllWindows
        If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then

            Set objIterator = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            For x = 0 To objIterator.Windows.Count
                On Error Resume Next
                current_title = objIterator.Windows(x).Document.Title
                current_url = objIterator.Windows(x).Document.Location

                If InStr(1, current_title, "Industry Support Siemens") > 0 Then 'is this my webpage?
                    Set IE = objIterator.Windows(x)
                    MsgBox "IE was properly set"
                    GoTo startProcess
                     Boolean_indicator = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        Set objIterator = Nothing
    Next ow
    Boolean_indicator = True
    Loop
    MsgBox "Webpage was not found."
    Exit Sub 
startProcess:
    Set myDoc = IE.Document

'****************************************
'   Your operative code here






'****************************************/
    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    Set IE = Nothing
 End Sub
```